# android: calling a method each time a button is clicked

Tags: android, button

i would like to create a class, which extends Button and implement a method, which is alwasy called, when the Button is clicked. But i still want it's OnClickListener to be called.
My Idea is to save the OnClickListener into a private member when the constructor or setOnClickListener is called and then set the OnClickListener to my own OnClickListener. This one would then call my method and the saved OnClickListener.
But i don't see how i can get the OnClickListenr, i only see, how to set it.
Is there a way to acces it?
Or do you have a better idea? (it doesn't matter wheter my method is called before or after the OnClickListener)

Comment: See following example [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: so what? this only shows how to set the OnClickListener, not how to get it...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this:

```
public class OnceClickedTwiceRunButton extends Button{

public OnceClickedTwiceRunButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OnceClickedTwiceRunButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
}

public OnceClickedTwiceRunButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private OnClickListener extraClickMethod;

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener newListener)
{  
    super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DefaultClickMethod(v);

            if(extraClickMethod != null)  
            {
                extraClickMethod.onClick(v);
            }
        }           
    });
    extraClickMethod = newListener;
}
private void DefaultClickMethod(View v)
{
    //TODO
}
}
```